# How can I see my .csv file data in the output client area of Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

After getting read my data in .csv file, I want to see all of them in the window area. I tried to use `TextOut()` but I didn't make it.

Comment: TextOut is intended for writing some text, not a file. You should write what you actually tried and what happens.

Comment: I am trying to write the text in my file. What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to display text is to use an edit control (with the multiline style set if you have multiple lines). Just call SetWindowText for the edit control with the text to display.

Comment: But I don't use any edit control. Do you suggest me to add a text box and then use this function?

Comment: @Ugur Sahin: Yes, that is what I suggest. It is a lot of work to display text well, and that work can be done for you by the edit control.